# Weird behavior of dragged fallback item when dragging an item from nested list

Tags: reactjs, sortablejs

I'm developing a list of items which can has nested list. I need a possibility to rearrange items in the root list and nested lists. Also, where should be the possibility to drag items between the root list and nested lists.

To implement these features I'm using [react-sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/react-sortablejs).

When I'm dragging an item from root list to a nested list, everything works fine. But when I'm dragging an item from nested list to root list my fallback item is jumping over the page. It seems like it happened when the item is moved out of the nested sortable area.

In case I disable `forceFallback={false}` everything works fine. But now I don't have my custom fallback item. What can cause this kind of problem?

The behaviour of my list you can see in [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qVcmb-MN1sNRcwuwIp6wYLI3xvLmdIXx/view?usp=sharing)